# Необходимо написать арифметический тест детали проблем расписаны в коде ранее давались правки участниками сообщества

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import random
a = str(random.randrange(2,10))
b = random.choice("+" "-" "*")
c = str(random.randrange(2,10))
d = (a, b, c)
print(d)
e = str(input("> "))
if e == d:
    print("Right!")
else:
    print("Wrong!")
```

необходим вывод по типу 2 + 2 или 8 * 3 который на который будет давать ответ пользовательский ввод
а потом код будет писать правильный ответ или не но проблема в том что он постоянно выдает что ответ не верный даже когда он является верным ,я понимаю что строки и числа не особо совместимы и из за этого код выдает не правильный ответ но генерация как и чисел так и строковых элементов должна быть рандомна, пожалуйста что необходимо дать точный ответ как надо переделать код что бы вывод был таким:

```
5 * 5
> 25
Right!
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Почитайте про `eval`, например.

Comment: Не вопрос, а поток неокрепшего сознания какой-то.

Comment: может, все таки, возьмешь наконец учебник и чему-нибудь научишься сам. Или хотя бы осилишь прочитать, что написано к предыдущим вопросам

Comment: и тут еще тоже самое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1379398/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-wrong-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-22-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b6%d1%83-4-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял у вас проблема в том что не срабатывает условие. Это происходит потому что в строке кода `if e == d:` вы буквально пытаетесь сравнить кортеж `('3', '*', '8')` и строку полученную в ответ от пользователя, строка там потому что метод `input()` всегда возвращает строку. Быстрым решением можно назвать такой код:

```
import random
a = str(random.randrange(2,10))
b = random.choice("+" "-" "*")
c = str(random.randrange(2,10))
d = (a, b, c)
print(d)
e = str(input("> "))
if int(e) == eval(''.join(d)):
    print("Right!")
else:
    print("Wrong!")
```

Что изменилось? Во первых методом `int()` мы превращаем строку которая пришла от пользователя в число. Во вторых мы при помощи `join()` объединяем все элементы кортежа в одну строчку, например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После полученная строка с примером попадает в функцию `eval()`. Данная функция исполняет python код и возвращает результат. Получив на вход строку '3*8' `eval()` решает этот пример и возвращает ответ в виде числа.
Дальше мы просто сравниваем полученной от пользователя число и ответ на пример.
Вывод:

Верное решение:

```
('8', '+', '9')
> 17
Right!
```

Не верное решение:

```
('4', '*', '9')
> 143
Wrong!
```

Этот код является плохим, по нескольким причинам:

1. Не информативные названия переменных
2. Использование `eval()` делает код не безопасным, лучше будет заменить эту функцию на какой нибудь алгоритм.
3. Нету никакой проверки на то что ввёл пользователь